# Move content of searched folder up one level

Tags: powershell

[Move files up one folder level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51346965/move-files-up-one-folder-level) might seem like a duplicate, but it is not.

Folder Structure

```
D:.
└───test
    └───Download
        └───First
        └───Second
        └───Third
```

When I run the following script the `Download` folder is moved up one level.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "Download" | Move-Item -Destination ".\.."
```

Current Output

```
D:.
└───test
└───Download
    └───First
    └───Second
    └───Third
```

But, I want everything inside the `Download` folder to moved up one level.

Expected Output

```
D:.
└───test
    └───Download
    └───First
    └───Second
    └───Third
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what if you hardcode the path of destination

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path "Download" | Move-Item -Destination ".\.."`  Exactly what this does will depend on your current working directory.

Comment: Even though you claim your question is not a duplicate, it absolutely is. You're suffering from the exact same problem (enumerating the *folder* whose content you want to move rather than the *files* and then moving *that folder* instead of its content). And the solution is also very much the same. Please re-read my answer to the other question.

Comment: If you read my answer again you may notice that you were *supposed* to do either `$folder = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "Download"; Get-ChildItem $folder | % {...}` or `Get-ChildItem "Download\*" | % {...}`.

Comment: Does my answer say to use `.\..` as the destination?

Comment: **Solution:** `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "Download"  | Get-ChildItem | Move-Item -Destination {$_.Directory.Parent.FullName}`